# Из массива рандомных чисел вывести в консоль количество чисел больше первого

Tags: javascript

```
     let max = 1000,
     min = 0
     let numA = Array();

     for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     let getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
     numA.push(getRandom)

     }

    console.log(numA)
```

Comment: Делаем счётчик. Пробегаемся циклом по массиву. Если значение на итерации больше, чем значение  по индексу 0, прибавляем счётчик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const max = 1000;
const min = 0;
const numbers = new Array();

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let getRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
    numbers.push(getRandom);
}

const filtered = numbers.filter((el) => el > numbers[0]);

console.log('Массив рандомных чисел', numbers);
console.log('Массив чисел, которые больше первого числа', filtered);
console.log('Количество чисел, которые больше первого числа', filtered.length);
```

Comment: а если min будет 5, то числа будут генерироваться меньше 5))

Comment: Причина в этом Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1)) ?

Comment: Да, но раз отсчёт с 0, то можно опустить это. А смысл? +0 -0

Answer (score 0):

```js
a=100,b=20;
console.log([...Array(8)].map(()=>Math.floor(Math.random()*(a-b+1)+b)).filter((e,_,c)=>e>c[0]).length);
```

Comment: Для меня этот код ещё космос !  Но однозначно есть к чему идти)

Comment: ну так писать конечно же не стоит,  я по приколу чисто